# The continuity of a function of two variables, how can we determine it exists?

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

if we find that limit for x-axis and y-axis exist does is it enough to say there is continuity?

or we have always to look in circle way around the point?

for example:
$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0) } \frac{xy^{3}}{x^{2}+y^{6}}$ , when (x,y)=(0,0) the value is zero of the function

for partition limits of x and y the limit is 0.

then we check when y=mx (I also i need an explanation on that as to how it works) also the limit is 0.

so far we also can't conclude that the function is continuous right?

then we do $x=ky^{3}$ that we $k=1$ the limit is 0.5, so that's when we can say the function isn't continuous.

but how did they determine the $x=ky^{3}$ part? based on what? and what is the meaning of $x=ky^{3}$ graphical wise?

Comment: You have to guess. Since the denominator is $x^2+y^6$ ,we should take $x=y^3$.If limit along  $x$ axis or $y$ axis doesn't exist or limit along both lines exist but are not equal then   the function isn't continuous but if limit along x,y axes exist and are equal then it doesn't say anything about continuity.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x,y)=\frac{xy^{3}}{x^{2}+y^{6}}$ if $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$ and $f(0,0)=0.$

1. show that , for $x \ne 0$, we have $f(x,mx)=\frac{m^3x^2}{1+m^6x^4}$. Hence $f(x,mx) \to 0$ as $x \to 0.$
2. show that , for $y \ne 0$, we have $f(y^3,y)= 1/2.$. Hence $f(y^3,y) \to 1/2$ as $y \to 0.$